# Cyclopark Sportive Kent

Tags: road-bike, uk

I love riding my bike and am looking at my first challenge! I've seen a sportive in October from Cyclopark, I've not been there and not sure of the roads the route is on, looks hilly!! Has anyone seen info or know the roads?  All help gratefully accepted for a newbie!!

Comment: Gidday and welcome - Might be a good idea to browse the Tour which can be found in the Help menu.  Your question is quite broad, and is likely to be closed as too broad.  Can you use the Edit link to ask more specific questions?  Also use Search to see if your questions already have an answer.   On the plus side, group racing is a lot of fun.

Comment: Also, I edited your question to add tags - its not immediately clear what country you're referring to.  I've guessed UK because "sportive" is not a common word.   If I've made a mistake please use edit to correct.

Comment: A sportive (aka gran fondo) isn't a race, for various reasons.

Comment: @srank while true there's enough in common that the tag is probably sensible (unless there's a more specific one).

Answer (score 1):

The [CycloPsycho 2016](https://www.cyclopark.com/enterprise/event-cyclopsycho2016) ("A major test of skill and nerve") takes place on Sunday, 30th October 2016.

> [image: map and hills[2]]
>
> **Where is it?**
>
> Starting and finishing at Cyclopark in Kent, this killer sportive takes in some of the most feared and steepest climbs Kent has to offer. All routes start with a lap of the circuit and head straight out into the surrounding country side.  Avoiding busy main roads is a real bonus compared to many sportive routes.
>
> **Why ride it?**
>
> Not one for the faint-hearted, with 13 categorised climbs and over 7,500 feet of climbing, on the long route, this ride is sure to test the legs of any rider.
>
> The Long Route> 88 miles  Start 8:30am
>
> The Medium Route> 67 miles Start 9:00am
>
> The Short Route> 28 miles  Start 9:30am

Comment: Thankyou, very hilly then!! Looks a good challenging course from that!!